# Can't boot Ubuntu from Grub after installing Slitaz

Tags: dual-boot, lubuntu, grub2

After installing Slitaz today I wanted to create a dualboot with Lubuntu I had installed before. Somehow the Grub doesn't load Lubuntu (error 15). I've added a screenshot of the current menu.lst

Can anyone help me with this? I just wanted to test Slitaz, but now I seem to have lost all access to my Ubuntu!!

[image: Screenshot of menu.lst]

Answer (score 1):

Slitaz installed grub 1 (legacy) and it looks as if it did not add in the Ubuntu initrd.

At that screen, hit <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the ubuntu stanza , and add a line

```
initrd /boot/initrd.img-2.6.30.6-generic
```

After booting ubuntu, reinstall grub

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

It should recognize slitaz as well.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this doesn't work either. I added the line in the GRUB by pressing 'e'. Still error 15 occurs...

Comment: You have the wrong root then. Boot a live CD and determine which partition is Ubuntu . `root (hd0,0)` or `root (hd0,1)`. You can also follow this link for how to recover https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: oh wait...I now get error 17 (cannot mount selected partition). I get this because I added your line and changed hd0,22 to hd0,1 in the menu.lst. Am I getting closer?

Comment: Doing it right now

Comment: I couldn't get it right, so I just reinstalled Ubuntu completely. I will not try slitaz again for some time...